# Kafka Cassandra Connector nested column from avro schema

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How do I access the nested field from AVRO schema.

For Example I have the following Schema :

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Person",
  "namespace": "com.datamountaineer.kcql.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Address",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "street",
            "type": {
              "type": "record",
              "name": "Street",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "name": "name",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "street2",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "Street"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "city",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "state",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "zip",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "country",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to access the nested fields here So I have tried below 
Query :

```
SELECT name, address.street.*, address.street2.name as streetName2 FROM topic
```

But getting below Error :

> Address.street.* not available in schema

Can any one help me. How do I get ?